# insert sql result inside array in yii 1

Tags: php, yii, yii1.x

I need execute following sql in yii 1 application.

```
select user_group.user_id and user_rights.region_id 
from user_rights inner join user_group on
 user_rights.user_group_id=user_group.user_group_id
```

and to retrieve only all region_ids and paste it inside array?
(e.g

```
                $regions = array();
                $regions[]='1';
                $regions[]='2';
```

)
How can I do it using foreach(or another way) in yii 1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try with this query:** you will get all region_id . You can use as your wish by foreach loop etc.

```
 Yii::app()->db->createCommand()
    ->select('user_rights.region_id')
    ->from('user_rights')
    ->join('user_group', 'user_rights.user_group_id=user_group.user_group_id')
    ->queryAll();
```

Also for creating query in Yii please read more here: [DOCs](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.query-builder)